# How to do a preview of different browsers/email clients?

Tags: asp.net, email, email-client

Hi I got a task from my boss to do a email previewer for different mails/browsers/clients. How should approach this task? How is such a thing done?

**EDIT:**
A tool to see how an email will render in different email clients

Comment: What is an "email previewer"? A tool to see how an email will render in different email clients? A tool to see a snippit of an email before opening it to see the whole thing in a webmail client? A tool to work out what email address would be given to an account on a system based on some set of rules? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the vagaries of email clients, I'd probably look at having a farm of VMs running various email clients, then automate emailing them, opening the emails, and taking screenshots.

Comment: I think I will do this option

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more (less expensive) options for previewing your email: http://www.previewmyemail.com and http://www.emailonacid.com. I am a big fan of Email on Acid because they provide tools for helping to resolve issues quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you read this article http://www.smartinsights.com/email-marketing/email-creative-copywriting/email-preview-tools/ . Here are the list of application for previewing the email.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few companies with software dedicated to this.  2 such companies: http://litmusapp.com/email-previews and http://pivotalveracity.com/